# How to append the new line character in php json response

Tags: php, jquery

I need to append the new line character in jsonencode .

My string :-

```
    $event_details ='';
       foreach($res as $k=>$val){ 
         $event_details  .= "{title:'".$val['event_name']."',";
         $event_details  .= "start:'".$val['start_date']."',";
         $event_details  .= "description:'".$val['event_detail']."'," ;
         $event_details  .= "url:'".$val['event_detail']."'," ;
         $event_details  .= "}," ;
       }

       Now I got  output Like is  
{title:'venuer request event 29-08-2015',start:'2015-09-02',description:'venuer request event
 29-08-2015',url:'venuer request event 29-08-2015',},{title:'test event2',start:'2015-08-31',description:'test events1',url:'test events1', },{title:'venuer request event2',start:'2015-08-31',description:'venuer request event2',url:'venuer request event2',},{title
:'singer request event2',start:'2015-08-31',description:'singer request event2',url:'singer
 request event2',}
```

But I need output like this :

```
   events: [
        {
            title: 'Event1',
            start: '2015-08-04',
            description :'sample',
            url :'http://localhost.com/melodic_svn/singer/soniya-42',

        },
        {
            title: 'Event2',
            start: '2015-08-25',
            description :'sample1',
            url :'http://localhost.com/melodic_svn/singer/soniya-42'
        }

    ],
```

Comment: Why don't you use json_encode? You can flag with JSON_PRETTY_PRINT int order to achieve your output

Comment: That's not JSON you generate there manually, but JSOL. (You could have added `\n` yourself however). But your simplistic approach will fail as soon as any variables contain quotes; lack of escaping, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP got a neat little function called `json_encode`. Now, you don't want to add your current string to the `json_encode` function, but rather a object or array instead. Why? Well, cause you really don't want to manually put json strings together like that.
Instead of creating a string in the for-each loop, all you have to do is add the properties to an `array` and then pass it to the `json_encode` function and use the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag.

Example:

```
$event_details = array();
foreach($res as $event){
   $eventArray = [
     'title' => $event['event_name'],
     'start' => $event['start_date'], 
     ... And so on ...
   ];
   array_push($event_details, $eventArray);
}
$json = json_encode($event_details, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\r\n` in double quotes in PHP:

```
   $event_details ='';

   foreach($res as $k=>$val){ 
     $event_details  .= "{\r\ntitle:'".$val['event_name']."',\r\n";
     $event_details  .= "start:'".$val['start_date']."',\r\n";
     $event_details  .= "description:'".$val['event_detail']."',\r\n" ;
     $event_details  .= "url:'".$val['event_detail']."',\r\n" ;
     $event_details  .= "},\r\n" ;
   }
```

Comment: `in double quotes` ftw!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$res = [
    [
        "event_name" => "dfgdf",
        "start_date" => "324235",
        "event_details" => "gfdgdfg"
    ],
    [
        "event_name" => "dfgdf2",
        "start_date" => "324235_2",
        "event_details" => "gfdgdfg2"
    ]
];

$event_details = [];
foreach ($res as $k => $v) {
    $event_details[$k]['title'] = $v['event_name'];
    $event_details[$k]['start'] = $v['start_date'];
    $event_details[$k]['description'] = $v['event_details'];
    $event_details[$k]['url'] = $v['event_details'];
}

echo json_encode($event_details, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```

Just build a new array with your desired structure and json_encode it. There's a very nice flag for encoding `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` which does exactly what you want. If you run it in console you will see the beautified output. If you run it in browser - click view source.

Output in the view source tab:

```
[
    {
        "title": "dfgdf",
        "start": "324235",
        "description": "gfdgdfg",
        "url": "gfdgdfg"
    },
    {
        "title": "dfgdf2",
        "start": "324235_2",
        "description": "gfdgdfg2",
        "url": "gfdgdfg2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your $event_details use the following 3 lines after all the json data get populated

```
$openBracket = str_replace("{","{\n",$event_details);
$comma = str_replace(",",",\n",$openBracket);
$closeBracket = str_replace(",",",\n",$comma);
```

After this just print the $closeBracket variable just like the below

```
echo $closeBracket;
```

Let me know if it is working

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to append any new line to items
just enclose it in `pre` tags

```
echo "<pre>";
//if printing php array
print_r($events);

//if printing json object
//print_r(json_decode($events));
echo "</pre>";
```